# Want to add completionListner in this code but don't know how to add and where to add

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
private void requestPickupHere(String uid) {
        DatabaseReference dbRequest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PickupRequest");
        GeoFire mGeoFire = new GeoFire(dbRequest);
        mGeoFire.setLocation(uid,new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()));


        if (mUserMarker.isVisible())
            mUserMarker.remove();
        //Add new marker
        mUserMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Pickup Here")
                .snippet("")
                .position(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

        mUserMarker.showInfoWindow();

        btnPickupRequest.setText("Getting your Driver ....");
    }
```

**Want to add completion listner here but I don't know where to add these lines of code given below**

Try add CompletionListener like

```
geoFire.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {@override
public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {        }
```

don't know where to add these lines please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it as parameter to setLocation call.
In your case:

```
GeoFire mGeoFire = new GeoFire(dbRequest);
mGeoFire.setLocation(uid, new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Full code:

```
private void requestPickupHere(String uid) {
    DatabaseReference dbRequest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PickupRequest");
    GeoFire mGeoFire = new GeoFire(dbRequest);
    mGeoFire.setLocation(uid, new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
            // your code here, this is listener
        }
    });


    if (mUserMarker.isVisible())
        mUserMarker.remove();
    //Add new marker
    mUserMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .title("Pickup Here")
        .snippet("")
        .position(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

    mUserMarker.showInfoWindow();

    btnPickupRequest.setText("Getting your Driver ....");
}
```

Comment: Where to add these line?

Comment: @ALIRAZA see your code, I just added listener to your setLocation method

Comment: Sir can I get  your email ?please

Comment: @ALI RAZA why ??

Comment: and please can you post this code again by adding the listener to it, please I don't have much time sir